# Passenger stop to write log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

```
Started GET "/home" for 117.55.68.xxx at 2012-11-05 22:56:06 +0900
Processing by PageController#home as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"420"}


Started POST "/login" for 61.211.5.107 at 2012-11-05 23:25:52 +0900
Processing by UsersController#login as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxx=", "username"=>"***DELETED***", "password"=>"***DELETED***", "commit"=>"login"}
Rendered users/login.html.haml within layouts/application (6.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 142ms (Views: 103.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I am using passenger 3.0.11.
I have encountered the problem that the log is not written.
It's happen when the "Completed" is not output.
After "Completed" is not output, log is not written for 20-40 minutes.

Does anyone have idea?

Comment: It might be rails logger problem.I was using Rails3.2.0 but It solves when Rails version upgrade to 3.2.8. see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4277.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have a memory issue.  Ruby cannot write to log because it has run out of memory.